# Data attr updated in the DOM but can't call it in jQuery

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using the [THUMBNAIL GRID WITH EXPANDING PREVIEW](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) from Codrops and am attempting to add additional data attributes to the expanded view link.  I have successfully added the attribute to the click element and have altered the jQuery to inject the data attribute to each new 'visit website' link.  When I click each picture, the dropdown is populated appropriately.  I can grab my data attribute (called `data-reveal-id`) and the correct data is returned.  When I switch to a new element however, the data attribute is updated in the DOM, but when I grab it via jQuery, I get the old attribute.  Below is an example:

on first click:

```
html:
<a href="#" class="redeem-btn" data-reveal="" data-id="1" data-reveal-id="emailModal">Redeem this Package</a>

jquery: $('a.redeem-btn')
return: <a href="#" class="redeem-btn" data-reveal="" data-id="1" data-reveal-id="emailModal">Redeem this Package</a>

jquery: $('a.redeem-btn').data('revealId')
return: "emailModal"
```

so far, so good.  Everything looks as it should.

on the second click (open a new dropdown):

```
html:
<a href="#" class="redeem-btn" data-reveal="" data-id="3" data-reveal-id="printModal">Redeem this Package</a>

jquery: $('a.redeem-btn')
return: <a href="#" class="redeem-btn" data-reveal="" data-id="3" data-reveal-id="printModal">Redeem this Package</a>

jquery: $('a.redeem-btn').data('revealId')
return: "emailModal"
```

When i return the entire `<a>` element, I see the correct `data-reveal-id` value of `"printModal"`.  When I try to grab just the data however, it returns the old value of `"emailModal"`

Can anyone help to explain this?  How can I get the correct data value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` stores data internally, and gets that data when it exists, otherwise it gets the value of the data attribute.

What you're looking for is the data attribute, and you've already set data to the internal store, but still want to get the value of the attribute, and you'll do that like so

```
$('a.redeem-btn').attr('data-revealId')
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution.. thank you.  I research this concept a bit further as well..thanks again